# Queue implementation using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, generics, queue, pointers

I am trying out different data structures to learn more about smart pointers. I have created a queue implementation which has `push`, `pop`, `front`, `back` and `size` functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T>
class Queue
{
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> q_ptr;
    int front_idx = -1;
    int back_idx = -1;
    int capacity = 0;
public:
    Queue(std::size_t space)
    {
        q_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[space]);
        capacity = space;
    }
    void push(T value);
    void pop();
    T front() const;
    T back() const;
    std::size_t size() const;
};

template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::push(T value)
{
    if(front_idx == -1)
    {
        front_idx++;
    }
    if(back_idx - front_idx + 1 == capacity)
    {
        std::cerr << "Queue full\n";
        return;
    }
    q_ptr[++back_idx] = value;
}

template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::pop()
{
    if(front_idx == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "Empty queue\n";
        return;
    }
    q_ptr[front_idx++] = T{};
}

template<typename T>
T Queue<T>::front() const
{
    return q_ptr[front_idx];
}

template<typename T>
T Queue<T>::back() const
{
    return q_ptr[back_idx];
}

template<typename T>
std::size_t Queue<T>::size() const
{
    return back_idx - front_idx + 1;
}

int main()
{
    Queue<int> q1{20};
    q1.pop();
    for(int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        q1.push(i);
    }
    std::cout << "Queue size: " << q1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Queue front: " << q1.front() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Queue back: " << q1.back() << "\n";
    q1.pop();
    std::cout << "Queue size: " << q1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Queue front: " << q1.front() << "\n";
    q1.pop();
    std::cout << "Queue size: " << q1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Queue front: " << q1.front() << "\n";
    q1.push(12);
    std::cout << "Queue size: " << q1.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Queue back: " << q1.back() << "\n";
}
```

1. The attempt is to use `unique_ptr` as an array similar to a raw pointer. Is the usage and approach correct? Can it be improved?
2. As far as I know, I cannot use `shared_ptr` this way in C++11 or C++14. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44950534/4834108) the best approach with `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I think your usage of `unique_ptr` is correct. The only recommendation I would make is to use `make_unique` for construction:

```
explicit Queue(std::size_t space) : 
    q_ptr(std::make_unique<T[]>(space)), 
    capacity(space) {}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22571331/9052753) provides motivation for its use. I've also used `explicit` to avoid implicit conversion from `size_t` to `Queue`. And I made use of a member initialization list.

I wrote the following tests using googletest:

```
TEST(QueueTester, testEmpty) {
    Queue<int> queue(0);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, queue.size());
}

TEST(QueueTester, testSingle) {
    Queue<int> queue(1);
    EXPECT_EQ(0, queue.size());
    queue.push(0);
    EXPECT_EQ(1, queue.size());
}
```

But neither passed. I corrected this by using the following:

```
int front_idx = 0;
```

And changing `push`:

```
template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::push(T value)
{
    if (back_idx - front_idx + 1 == capacity)
    {
        std::cerr << "Queue full\n";
        return;
    }
    q_ptr[++back_idx] = value;
}
```

I changed `front` and `back` to return references to the elements to allow the user to modify the contents. I also wrote overloads for returning `const` references to allow reading when the `Queue` is passed by `const` reference:

```
template<typename T>
T &Queue<T>::front()
{
    return q_ptr[front_idx];
}

template<typename T>
T &Queue<T>::back()
{
    return q_ptr[back_idx];
}

template<typename T>
const T &Queue<T>::front() const
{
    return q_ptr[front_idx];
}

template<typename T>
const T &Queue<T>::back() const
{
    return q_ptr[back_idx];
}
```

I further noticed that `push`, given a nonzero `front_idx`, will write past the end of the array pointed to by `q_ptr`. I took inspiration from [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-set-1introduction-and-array-implementation/) and modified the code to store elements circularly around the array. Here is the final implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T>
class Queue
{
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> q_ptr;
    int front_idx = 0;
    int back_idx = -1;
    std::size_t _size = 0;
    std::size_t capacity;
public:
    explicit Queue(std::size_t space) :
        q_ptr(std::make_unique<T[]>(space)),
        capacity(space)
    {
    }
    void push(T value);
    void pop();
    bool full();
    bool empty();
    T &front();
    T &back();
    const T &front() const;
    const T &back() const;
    std::size_t size() const;
};

template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::push(T value)
{
    if (full())
    {
        std::cerr << "Queue full\n";
        return;
    }
    back_idx = (back_idx + 1) % capacity;
    q_ptr[back_idx] = value;
    ++_size;
}

template<typename T>
bool Queue<T>::full()
{
    return _size == capacity;
}

template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::pop()
{
    if (empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Empty queue\n";
        return;
    }
    q_ptr[front_idx] = T{};
    front_idx = (front_idx + 1) % capacity;
    --_size;
}

template<typename T>
bool Queue<T>::empty()
{
    return _size == 0;
}

template<typename T>
T &Queue<T>::front()
{
    return q_ptr[front_idx];
}

template<typename T>
T &Queue<T>::back()
{
    return q_ptr[back_idx];
}

template<typename T>
const T &Queue<T>::front() const
{
    return q_ptr[front_idx];
}

template<typename T>
const T &Queue<T>::back() const
{
    return q_ptr[back_idx];
}

template<typename T>
std::size_t Queue<T>::size() const
{
    return _size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am using C++11 in this case. So it does not have `make_unique`. But thank you for the suggestion.